# What is quantum computing going to mean for digital audio/music?

Tags: computer

What is quantum computing going to mean for digital audio/music?

Comment: Nothing, we already have more quality than we need. 

Comment: @Sound1844 In some specific fields it could have a significant effect - for example, in game audio, the amount of system resources budgeted to sound can often be limited - having those restrictions lifted could be a big change.

Comment: I was thinking of really good pitchshifting / vocal emulation's? To not have an instrument, but a "musician" as a plug-in?
Just fantasizing...

Comment:   @Bram "To not have an instrument, but a "musician" as a plug-in?". Algorithmic music is an old topic and practiced/studied as of today. Although as a computationally expensive field, it could be improved by more computing power. Audio simulation ought be another computation intensive area that ought to benefit, although that I think is more about how much interest there is to develop simulations (it's traditionally been very research-oriented, small scale and non-commercial/not for real use), and the problem is generally the complexity of the algorithms, not necessarily computing power. 

Answer (score 3):

Just more power in a smaller package (which though lends itself well for improving real-time audio, which, as you may have noticed, is quite of a resource hog even in today's standards). Quantum computing is mainly a computer technology topic and one of its major motivations is to extend Moore's law to even smaller devices with less power consumption and more power. There's no suggestion that quantum computing would seem any way different to a computer user, eventhough the technology opens up to certain interesting topics (and applications) in how computing is done or what quantum computing can be used to do (as opposed to the current computer architectures), it's just different "under the hood".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe more precise FFT resynthesis?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2017-03/qmuo-qpo031317.php
This reference "describes for the first time the use of the Filter Diagonalisation Method (FDM) in music signal processing. The technique has origins in quantum physics and is employed to study molecular dynamics and nuclear magnetic resonance."

I begin to imagine how quantum phenomena could represent music generated by a quantum computer..